# Translate conditional operators in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm just starting out with verilog and came across this piece of code on a project I was looking at. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it even after looking up the meaning of the operators.

```
assign sec_next = (clr || sec_reg == divisor && (state_reg == on)) ? 4'b0 : (state_reg == on) ? sec_reg + 1 : sec_reg;
```

Could someone maybe translate it to if else statements so I could understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
always@* begin
  if(clr || (sec_reg == divisor)&&(state_reg == on))
        sec_next = 4'b0;
  else if((state_reg == on))
        sec_next = sec_reg + 1;
  else  sec_next = sec_reg;
end
```

Hope this will clear your doubt!! learn about the ternary operator in verilog.

Comment: This is logically correct, but keep in mind that the example here will not compile due to the wire/reg assignments. It also will behave differently in presence of unknown ('x') values.

Comment: yeah @serge as user is concerned about the understanding of code ,i have given simple code ,once user learn about ternary operator user will get to know the `x` issue.